# 500 error on index.php with nginx + php-fpm

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vps, wordpress

Before starting, I'd like to ssay this is my first experience with `VPS`, I have an Ubuntu 18.04 64bit minimal server.

> For everything I tried so far I didn't tried using complex application. Just plain html file with `Hello` message and WordPress blank installation.

To begin with, I'm installing `Vesta Panel` because it's easier for me to control some basic tasks and configurations. In order to install this panel, I'm using `nginx + php-ftpm`. After I install WordPress with this configuration I'm getting 500 error with this message:

```
2020/06/23 23:09:09 [error] 12335#12335: *11 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "example.com"
```

This error only appears when I try to access the WordPress index page, or any file with the naem `index.php`, if it's an `index.html` file it loads properly.

---

After that I restored the `VPS` and installed `Vesta Panel` using `nginx + apache`. With this configuration, WordPress is working as expected. When I access my domain `example.com` the steps to create an WordPress website appears as expected.

With both configurations, the folder holding all the websites files is `/home/admin/web/{domain.com}/public_html`.

---

Edit: As requested in the comments, I'm adding more information to the question.

`systemctl status php-fpm.service` returns:

```
php-fpm.service - LSB: starts php7.2-fpm
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/php-fpm; generated)
Active: active (exited) since Wed 2020-06-24 01:44:40 UTC; 10h ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Tasks: 0 (limit: 614)
CGroup: /system.slice/php-fpm.service

Jun 24 01:44:40 agdevision.com.br systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts php7.2-fpm...
Jun 24 01:44:40 agdevision.com.br systemd[1]: Started LSB: starts php7.2-fpm.
```

`sudo journalctl -u php-fpm.service` returns:

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2019-03-08 08:44:31 UTC, end at Wed 2020-06-24 12:08:35 UTC. --
Jun 24 01:44:40 agdevision.com.br systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts php7.2-fpm...
Jun 24 01:44:40 agdevision.com.br systemd[1]: Started LSB: starts php7.2-fpm.
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! We probably need more information to help you out. What does your NGINX configuration look like? Does `netstat -tn` show a running php-fpm process on port 9001?

Comment: @MartinKonrad About nginx config, where exactly is this information located? About `netstat -tn`, I'm not seeing anything related to port 9001.

Answer (score 0):

The `php-fpm` service is running but it does not listen on port 9001. Please check your FPM configuration (usually in `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` on Debian/Ubuntu systems). The important parameter is the following:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
```

Don't forget to restart the FPM service by running `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service` after editing the file.

Comment: Inside this folder there is 2 files `www.conf` and with my domain name, like `domain.com.conf`. Both files have this `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` already set. Also, the file with my domain name already have `listen = 127.0.0.1:9001`. Anyway, I followed your steps and changed the `www.conf` file to add that line, reestarted the server but it didn't worked.

Comment: Please check your FPM log files in `/var/log` to see if it is reporting any errors during start.

Comment: I didn't knew where this log was. Thanks. It has this error `[pool www] unable to set listen address as it's already used in another pool 'domain.com' ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
ERROR: FPM initialization failed`

Comment: Inside Vesta Panel, under Web configuration, there is an option called `Backend Template (php-fpm)`, it has 3 options `default | no-php | socket`. I changed it to socket and now evrything is working. I removed the changes we've made before. Should I turn this into an answer?

Comment: Yes, please add this as an answer so it's obvious to others that this question has an answer.